# Moving a class to MainWindow broke the application

Tags: .net, wpf, class

I moved a class into the MainWindow and things broke badly with not compiler error

```
namespace poker 
{
    MainWindow
    {
       private static Card[] Cards = new .....
       public MainWindow()
       {
       }
    }
    public class Card  
    {
    }
}
```

Card need access to Cards
So I thought I would take a shortcut and just move Card

```
namespace poker 
{
    MainWindow
    {
       private static Card[] Cards = new .....
       public MainWindow()
       {
       }
       public class Card    // this broke stuff
       {
       }
    }
}
```

I think I could just pass Cards to Card in the ctor
Is that another approach?

And why did what I did break things
What happened the xaml broke on the xmlns:local and it never even got to calling the ctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML doesnt support nested classes

Comment: I think I believe you but do you by any chance have a reference

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379(v=vs.100).aspx -- "Your custom class must not be a nested class. Nested classes and the "dot" in their general CLR usage syntax interfere with other WPF and/or XAML features such as attached properties."

Comment: Also, you should put the `Card` class into it's own file instead of inside of the same one as MainWindow.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645020(v=vs.95).aspx
quote:- 'The custom class must not be a nested class'

Comment: @ChrisFannin Why?  I just need a couple classes on a pretty basic app.

Comment: Because that's proper design. Putting them all in the form results in the confusion you're having now, especially with XAML/WPF.

Comment: Sure would be nice if that was clear compiler error.